# How to handle language change within the app in iOS 9 with auto layout

Tags: localization, internationalization, storyboard, autolayout, ios9

I have to support different languages like English, Arabic, Japanese, etc.,  but the language changing option is available within the app itself. Earlier we have handled the right to left and left to right language changes in code.

From iOS 9 onwards, designed the UI with auto layout will be handled this properly, while changing the language in iPhone settings.

As per my requirement, I have changed the language within the app and updated the "AppleLanguages" key directly. But the storyboard is not updating properly. Once I force quit the app and relaunch it, then it working fine.

I have doubts in that,

Is there any solution to change this (language within the app) without restarting the app?

Answer (score 0):

There is this (https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift/blob/master/README.md), a nice library I've been playing with which will change languages on the fly and not require you to restart the app.  Does take some practice to figure out and uses NSObserver based strategy to update all the strings in the UI.